# Trying to perform setcap from Qt program

Tags: linux, qt, linux-capabilities

I'm trying to perform setcap from Qt program this way:

```
QProcess process;
QString command = "cat";
QStringList args;
args << _fileName;

process.start(command, args);
process.waitForFinished();

QString StdOut   = process.readAllStandardOutput();
QString StdError = process.readAllStandardError();
QString err      = process.errorString();



QProcess process_2;
command = "setcap";
args.clear();
args << "cap_kill=ep" << _fileName;

process_2.start(command, args);
process_2.waitForFinished();

StdOut   = process_2.readAllStandardOutput();
StdError = process_2.readAllStandardError();
err      = process_2.errorString();
```

As _fileName I use value from QFileSystemModel, in my case it looks like "/home/ekaterina/example".

The first part (which was written just to test path correctness) works fine and puts file content into StdOut. I expect the second part to return something like "operation is not permitted" as QtCreator is run its projects not as root. But I get "execvp: No such file or directory" in err string. How is that?

When I'm trying to run project executable with "cap_setfcap" capability I get exactly the same result.

Comment: Is `setcap` on your path?  Can you run the desired command in a terminal?

Comment: @G.M., yes, everything works fine from terminal (with sudo of course)

Comment: And you're running your application via `sudo` (or as `root`)?

Comment: @G.M., I've tried both options - set "chmod u+s" and "sudo setcap cap_setfcap executable", nothing helps

Comment: Take care. Under `sudo` `$PATH` might differ from what a regular user has. Compare `env | grep -E '^PATH'` with `sudo env | grep -E '^PATH'`. It is quite likely the `sudo` version looks in a directory a regular user doesn't.
`

Comment: @AndrewGMorgan, yes, they are different. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried just providing the full path to `setcap`?  Usually `/usr/sbin/setcap` or just `/sbin/setcap`.

Comment: @G.M., yes, that's it, thanks! Could you write your reply as an answer to close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do, as @G.M. suggests, is to provide the full path to the binary. You can find `setcap`'s location on your system with:

```
$ sudo which setcap
```

On Debian and Fedora, that returns `/usr/sbin/setcap`. On your system it might also be `/sbin/setcap`. Then embed that string in your program explicitly:

```
command = "/sbin/setcap";
```